# Unable to display Google basemap using Leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, google-maps, basemap, react

I am trying to display Google basemap using leaflet.js on web but getting strange results, screenshot is attached

[image]

I have also added the code for react component below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';

class MapEditor extends Component{
    state={}

    componentDidMount() {
        var map = L.map('map', {
            center:[30.2541,69.703431],
            zoom: 6})
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            subdomains:['mt0']
        }).addTo(map);
    };
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div id='mapeditor'>
                    <div id='map'>
                    </div>
                
            </div>
        )
    };
}

export default MapEditor;
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835758/leaflet-drawing-tiles-disjointly and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672846/how-to-load-a-google-maps-baselayer-in-leaflet-after-june-2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `L.tileLayer` link works for me. I used it in the minmal sample from LeafletJS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .leaflet-container {
            height: 400px;
            width: 600px;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([30.2541,69.703431], 13);

    var tiles =  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
      maxZoom: 19,
      subdomains:['mt0']
  }).addTo(map);
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could be an CSS issue or related to React.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late to answer but I replicated your code and it seems that you have not imported the Leaflet CSS.

Importing that fixed the issue for me. Updated code looks like this. (Make sure to add the CSS before you import Leafet as in the order shown below)

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
    import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
    import L from 'leaflet';

    //Rest of your code as it is
```